# Zermelo-Fraenkel Set Theory - Proving a condition for Kuratowski pairs

Tags: set-theory

Want to complete the proof of the following: Condition II holds for Kuratowski pairs. In other words, for all $A$, the set $\{$ $(a, b)$ : $a$ $\in$ $A$, $b$ $\in$ $A$ $\}$ exists.

We apply Seperation. The predicate $\phi$$(x)$ $\iff$ $($ $\exists$ $a$ $\in$ $A$ $)$ $($ $\exists$ $b$ $\in$ $A$ $)$ $($ $x$ $=$ $(a, b)$ $)$ . Observe that $(a, b)$ $=$ $\{$ {$a$}, {$a, b$} $\}$ $\in$ $\mathcal P$$\mathcal P$$A$ . So our bounding set will be $\mathcal P$$\mathcal P$$A$ ...

Comment: Now using separation the set $\{x\in\mathcal{PP}A\mid\exists a\exists b(x=(a,b))\}$ is a set. I *really* don't understand what sort of question you're asking here.

Comment: Condition II for ordered pairs says that, given sets $A$, $B$ the set $A$$\star$$B$ exists. We can see that $A$$\star$$B$ $\subset$ $($$A$$\cup$$B$$)$$\star$$($$A$$\cup$$B$$)$. So it is sufficient to check the condition in cases where we consider $A$$\star$$A$. Does this make it easier?

Comment: No, I understood that part. I don't understand *your* question. You found the formula with which you want to apply Separation; you found the set from which you want to separate... What sort of answer are you looking for here?